# Google Sheets Index Match Vlookup multiple results with Textjoin and trim split search keys

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am wondering if you could help me with this, I have 2 workbooks, one that is the main table and is a list of books with their respective authors, and each author individual author has an ID that is stored on the other workbook named AuthorData. My goal is to have a formula that looks for each author and returns their IDs on the same cell, separated by ", ". For example, I have book XYZ by ABC and DEF, ABC's ID is 123, and DEF's ID is 456; ABC and DEF are on the same cell, like [ABC, DEF] so I need it to read each author individually and return their ID's in one cell separated also by ", ", so it should be [123, 456]. I have tried with many different things but this has definitely beated me.

This is the best I could do:

```
=arrayformula(textjoin(", ";1;if(vlookup(trim(split(B2 ;","));importrange("1UaExMnHmTzp3YX1tzG5kBFV2rqvM6WTXZxbwNbywm60";"Data!B:B");1;0)=true;query(trim(split(B2 ;",")));index(importrange("1UaExMnHmTzp3YX1tzG5kBFV2rqvM6WTXZxbwNbywm60";"Data!A:A");match(trim(split(B2 ;","));importrange("1UaExMnHmTzp3YX1tzG5kBFV2rqvM6WTXZxbwNbywm60";"Data!B:B");0)))))
```

This somewhat works, it does multiple searches but it always looks for the first author, so in a case where there are multiple authors, it will return the ID of the first one as many times as authors there are.

This is the link of the main table: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IvYRhYI7IQM7xfDWiPjKj96E2yUGhDf225A3a2qlCyE/edit?usp=drivesdk

And this one is of the second table: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UaExMnHmTzp3YX1tzG5kBFV2rqvM6WTXZxbwNbywm60/edit?usp=drivesdk

Feel free to edit as you need, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added two new sheets: "Erik Help" and "Authors".

The "Authors" sheet contains a single `IMPORTRANGE` formula in A1, which brings in all the data from your source spreadsheet. Then, formulas within the current spreadsheet can simply refer to the data in the "Author" page, instead of using more `IMPORTRANGE` references.

From there, I reference the "Author" sheet within one formula in C1 of "Erik Help" (i.e., the "ID" column):

`=ArrayFormula({"ID";IF(A2:A="";;SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TRIM(SPLIT(B2:B&REPT(",X";10);","));{Authors!B:B\Authors!A:A};2;FALSE));ROWS(A2:A);10));" ";10)));" ";", "))})`

This one formula creates the header and all results for the column.

The formula itself is difficult to explain. But below are some of the key concepts.

`REPT` adds 10 repetitions of ",X" to the end of every string in `B2:B`. This assures that, when `SPLIT` we will have at least 10 items for each row. I chose the number 10, because it seems likely that no book will have more than 10 authors; and we will need uniformity for the rest of the formula.

`SPLIT` splits the string of author names and X'es into separate columns at the commas.

`TRIM` will remove extra spaces.

`VLOOKUP` will attempt to find every separate author name or X in a reversed array from the "Author" sheet, returning the ID number if found.

`IFERROR` will return null if nothing is found (which of course will happen for each X).

`ARRAY_CONSTRAIN` will limit the returned results to 10 virtual columns.

`TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(...` will create `QUERY` *headers* from all 10 results per row and then flip them to match the row-by-row data.

`TRIM` again makes sure there are no stray spaces.

`SUBSTITUTE` will exchange remaining spaces for ", ".